# Can you predict the residuals from a regularized regression using the same data?

Tags: regression, machine-learning

Suppose you run an OLS fit to data and compute the residuals. Then you fit the residuals to the data again. I know that in this case the coefficients will be zero. However, what if instead of OLS I run a regularized least squares (elastic net, lasso, ridge, etc.) regression. Suppose the model that does best in cross-validation only uses a small subset of the predictors. I then fit another regression to the residuals obtained with that small subset using the features that didn't make it in the final model.

Would that give me any information I didn't already have when I originally ran the regularized regression?